# Discord.py doesn't register cog

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to code a discord bot in python. I want to split the files to make it cleaner. So I got a bot.py and a responses.py. Now I want to create a command in the responses.py, so I created a cog. I solved all the errors it gave me when trying to set it up, there are no errors anymore but when I try the command in discord it doesn't work.

bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from responses import CommandsCog
import responses

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    intents.members = True

    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
    client.remove_command("help")

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="test"))
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')
        await client.add_cog(CommandsCog(client))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        response = await responses.handle_commands(message)
        if response:
            await message.channel.send(response)

        console = str(message.author)
        if message.author == client.user or console == "Console#5220":
            pass
        else:
            username = str(message.author)
            user_message = str(message.content)
            channel = str(message.channel)

            print(f'{username} said: "{user_message}" ({channel})')

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

responses.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class CommandsCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
#    @commands.cooldown(1, 1800, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def alarm(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("MSG")

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(CommandsCog(client))
```

I don't know what to try since it is not giving me any errors and I am a coding noob. I know there are people with similar issues, I looked at the answers, but I couldn't find what I did wrong. So I want to apologize, if this already has been answered.

Comment: I think you should name the variable as `bot` inside the `Cog`. Do not use `client`.

Comment: Is the `on_ready` event being fired?

Comment: @Hazzu The variable name is a preference thing, it does not make a difference. Also the `on_ready()` is being fired, it's just the cog that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The cog is not added because you run `add_cog()` instead of `load_extension()` in `bot.py`. The `add_cog()` method is only used in the cog itself in the `setup()` function.

As for your method of loading cogs, I've never seen this type of thing, I don't think it should even work, but maybe it does.

If you're trying to put your commands in cogs I recommend this solution:

```
# You need to import os for this method
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="test"))
    print(f'{client.user} is now running!')
    # Load cogs
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            print(f'loaded {filename}')
```

Create a folder named 'cogs' and put your cogs there, no need to import the cog's class in the `bot.py`, this function above will load all cogs in the folder named 'cogs'.

Also, where do you invoke `run_discord_bot()`? I don't see the function invoked anywhere, but it probably works because you didn't say you had problems running the bot.

Comment: Both ways to load the Cog are valid. I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Yeah, the cogs are "added", the problem here is not in the method of adding cogs. In `bot.py`, you **need** to use `load_extension()` instead of `add_cog()` otherwise it won't work. The question author said he was a _coding noob_ so I wanted to share a method I use to load cogs. But ultimately the problem is in that the wrong function was used for loading the cog.

Comment: You're wrong about that. Using `await bot.add_cog` is equivalent to using `await bot.load _extension`. After all, when you use 'load_extension', your program will be calling the `setup` function.

Comment: @DawoleQ 
I created a new file called test.py and put that in the cogs folder. Inside that test.py it basically looks exactly the same as in the responses.py from above. In the bot.py I added your lines of code to load the cogs. But when I try the command in discord nothing is happening. I did everything you said above. Also the bot runs fine, I just sent the parts of the code I thought would be necessary for you to help me solve my problem. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Hazzu I thought `load_extension()`must be used in the main file bc it didn't work for me otherwise, sorry for the mistake. Also, do commands in 'bot.py' work if you put them there? Maybe somethings wrong with the `on_message()` command processing?

Comment: That's probably the problem DawoleQ. @Xanderl when you use the `on_message` event, you are overwriting the default implementation of the Bot, which prevents commands from being processed. Add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of your `on_message` event.